# Pairwise correlation

Tags: python, pandas, split-apply-combine

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
In [45]: df 
Out[45]: 
   Item_Id  Location_Id  date  price
0        A         5372     1    0.5
1        A         5372     2    NaN
2        A         5372     3    1.0
3        A         6065     1    1.0
4        A         6065     2    1.0
5        A         6065     3    3.0
6        A         7000     1    NaN
7        A         7000     2    NaN
8        A         7000     3    NaN
9        B         5372     1    3.0
10       B         5372     2    NaN
11       B         5372     3    1.0
12       B         6065     1    2.0
13       B         6065     2    1.0
14       B         6065     3    3.0
15       B         7000     1    8.0
16       B         7000     2    NaN
17       B         7000     3    9.0
```

For every `Item_Id` in each `Location_Id` category, I want to compute a pairwise correlation of prices between every `Item_Id` pair. Please note that while I have only given two unique `Item_Id`
values in the sample data above, there are tens of different values that `Item_Id` takes on in my real data. I have tried using `groupby.corr()`, but this doesn't seem to give me what I want.

Ultimately, I want N dataframes where N is the number of unique `Location_Id` values in `df`. Each of the N dataframes will be a square correlation matrix of prices between all pairwise combinations of `Item_Id` present in a specific `Location_Id` category. So each of the N dataframes will have J rows and columns, where J is the number of unique `Item_Id` values in that specific `Location_Id` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `Location_Id` then pivot on `date` and `Item_Id` and get the correlations:

```
>>> corr = lambda obj: obj.pivot('date', 'Item_Id', 'price').corr()
>>> df.groupby('Location_Id').apply(corr)
Item_Id                  A      B
Location_Id Item_Id              
5372        A        1.000 -1.000
            B       -1.000  1.000
6065        A        1.000  0.866
            B        0.866  1.000
7000        A          NaN    NaN
            B          NaN  1.000
```

and you get a 2 x 2 matrix for each `Location_Id`.

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I needed. Thank you.